# Facebook Ad API PHP : Invalid OAuth access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-rest-api

I am working on the Facebook Ads API and I am totally new for this. I am getting an error to fetch the Ads account. The error is `Invalid OAuth access token.` After getting this error I came to google and searched a lot like 
[First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980586/facebook-ads-api-invalid-oauth-access-token) [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369756/facebook-php-oauth2-api-invalid-access-token) [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823018/facebook-graph-api-getting-invalid-oauth-access-token-after-3-https-calls). But didn't find any solution so I decided to come to Stackoverflow **so this question is not duplicate**

Here is the code how I used the Facebook Ads API

```
public function login() {

        $helper = $this->facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $this->request->session()->write('fb_access_token', false);
        $access_token =  $this->request->session()->read('fb_access_token');

        if ($access_token) {
            echo "You are logged in!";
          } else {
            $permissions = ['email', 'ads_management', 'pages_show_list', 'publish_pages', 'manage_pages', 'ads_read'];
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/FacebookManager/Adsmanagement/authenticate', $permissions);
            echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook</a>';
          }
    }

    public function authenticate() {
        if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
            $helper = $this->facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $_GET['state']);
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
            if($accessToken) {
                echo "got the token";
                $this->request->session()->write('fb_access_token', $accessToken);
                //echo $accessToken; 
                $oAuth2Client = $this->facebook->getOAuth2Client();
                $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);

                $this->facebook->setDefaultAccessToken($longLivedAccessToken);


            }
        }
    }
```

And I am getting the adaccount like this

```
public function getAdsAccount() {
        $accesstoken = $this->request->session()->read('fb_access_token');
        //$accesstoken = "AQwfmuNgKZCZCiZBuhAMGB8xZBty5dgNR7J9ZBO2ZCDl1SWYxnBLn9ahIn5FQTWxkJ0FPKbemeG0vUAwPsZCN2FFxOFey9BQr8CZBW07IwlZB0FK81SH8ozOil2GllR35BCyxQGhQ7JrtuCdNE6kjEOU0FZCAZDZD";
        Api::init(
            $this->app_id, // App ID
            $this->appsecret,
            $accesstoken // Your user access token
          );
        //*****************
        $account = new AdAccount('****************');
        $contracts = $account->read();

        echo "<pre>"; print_r($contracts->getData());
    }
```

So I am using a developer account, Trying to fetch this with the facebook test user from the APP dashboard-> Roles->Test User. I am setting the proper permissions etc. Don't know where I am wrong.

**Update**
Now the issue is if I create access token from [Graph Explorar](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/269911617059834) It works but if i create with SDK its giving me the error "invalid aouth Tokan"

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @manoj Kumar Please check with below URL with administrator login for app debug your `AccessToken`.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Please check below code from facebook PHP SDK for getting the valid access token with permission `ads_management`.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

// Init PHP Sessions
session_start();

$fb = new Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{your-app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{your-app-secret}',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

if (!isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = null;
}

if (!$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']) {
  $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
  try {
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $helper->getAccessToken();
  } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }
}

if ($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']) {
  echo "You are logged in!";
} else {
  $permissions = ['ads_management'];
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost:8888/marketing-api/', $permissions);
  echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook</a>';
}
```

After that, You have to get AdAccount so use below code

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;

// Add after Api::init()
$me = new AdUser('me');
$my_adaccount = $me->getAdAccounts()->current();
```

Comment: I tried then i got "You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v3.2." error

Comment: Hi, @ManojKumar I updated my code and share the screenshot of how to get the code from graph API.

Comment: I updated my SDK and now its working if i generate `access token` from graph exploral but not working if i create it with SDK. any idea?

Comment: Any error you generate when using through SDK so I help you with it. but the app in development mode its work only administrator and developer account.

Comment: Yes i am using it for the Users added in the APP.

Comment: Hi, @ManojKumar I do not see your screenshot. getting error 525.

Comment: Please check this docs link (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/sdks) and check all code.

Comment: I solved it, Actually, facebook return me an object of the access token. It also works with `echo` so that was my mistake `$accesstoken->getValue()` works.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually my mistake. Facebook API return us an protect object. If you print the variable it will display it as string.

```
<?php
echo $longLivedAccessToken;
var_dump($longLivedAccessToken);
?>
```

The output is something like 
[image]

I tried `$longLivedAccessToken->getValue();`

```
$oAuth2Client = $this->facebook->getOAuth2Client();
$longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
$accesstoken = $longLivedAccessToken->getValue();
$this->request->session()->write('fb_access_token', $accesstoken);
$this->facebook->setDefaultAccessToken($longLivedAccessToken);
```